# How to position a button in JavaFX scene ? ( Randomly )

Tags: java, javafx

I want somehow to make the button change his position randomly when i push the button. I've got one idea how to solve this problem, one of them i've highlighted below, but i already think that this is not what i need.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Ulesanne6 extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application.launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        primaryStage.setTitle("Test");
        Button btn = new Button();
        btn.setText("Hello");
        btn.setOnAction(new EventHandler <javafx.event.ActionEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(javafx.event.ActionEvent event) {
                //btn.setLayoutY(Math.random());
                //btn.setLayoutX(Math.random());
            }
        });

        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        root.getChildren().add(btn);
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 800, 600));
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

I think that somewhere here i suppose to do that, but i don't know how... yet.

```
public void handle(javafx.event.ActionEvent event) {
                //btn.setLayoutY(Math.random());
                //btn.setLayoutX(Math.random());
            }
```

Comment: Don't use `StackPane`. Use `Pane`. Also, make sure your `Math.random()` generates a number within the `Pane's` bounds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this?

```
        public void handle(javafx.event.ActionEvent event) {
            btn.setTranslateX(ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextDouble(800));
            btn.setTranslateY(ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextDouble(600));
        }
```

You might also want to make sure that the button is placed somewhere on the screen and not off the screen.  So if you know the width and height of the button, take it into account.

```
        public void handle(javafx.event.ActionEvent event) {
            btn.setTranslateX(ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextDouble(800 - buttonWidth));
            btn.setTranslateY(ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextDouble(600 - buttonHeight));
        }
```

EDIT:  Please note that you are using a `StackPane` as your root parent.  `StackPane` likes to position its children based on alignment attribute of the `StackPane`.  As such, for my answer to work correctly, you must make your root parent a `Group` instead of a `StackPane`.  A regular `Pane` can also work.

```
    Group root = new Group();
```

Comment: The OP's problem is that the OP is using `StackPane`. `StackPane` does not allow `Nodes` to be moved in this manner.

Comment: @Sedrick thanks for pointing that out.  Will update my answer.